How do I call external APIs in in a Next.js app?
I am designing a weather app as a resume project. I am trying to call WeatherAPI for current weather data as provided by their currentdata.json call. How do I actually do this in code?
I have a single page:
// /src/app/page.js
import Card from "@/lib/components/card";
import { fetchCurrentData } from "@/lib/data";

export default async function Page() {
  //fetching data...
  const currentWeather = await fetchCurrentData();

  //hardcoded card data for testing
  const currWeatherCardData = {
    top: 'Saturday, June 1st, 2024',
    main: '31\u00b0C',
    bottom: 'Sunny'
  };
  //more card data constants for other cards, same top/main/bottom...

  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col m-24 gap-8">
      <Card data={currWeatherCardData}/> 
      <Card data={highLowsCardData}/>
      <Card data={precipCardData}/>
      <Card data={uviCardData}/>
    </main>
  );
}


I'm trying to get fetchCurrentData() to call the API.
// src/lib/data.ts
export async function fetchCurrentData() {
  try {
    const currentData = await fetch('https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?q=LOCATION&key=APIKEY');
    console.log(currentData.json())
    return currentData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('API Error: ', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch current weather data.');
  }
}

fetchCurrentData() is returning a Response object, which I'm not quite sure how to parse and get it to page.js Specifically, for example, I'm not sure how to get the localtime from the JSON into one of the Cards as text.
For reference, the API GET request returns a JSON object that looks like:
{
  "location": {
    "name": "New York",
    "region": "New York",
    "country": "United States of America",
    "lat": 40.71,
    "lon": -74.01,
    "tz_id": "America/New_York",
    "localtime_epoch": 1717386775,
    "localtime": "2024-06-02 23:52"
  },
  "current": {
    "last_updated_epoch": 1717386300,
    "last_updated": "2024-06-02 23:45",
    "temp_c": 22.8,
    "temp_f": 73,
    "is_day": 0,
    "condition": {
      "text": "Partly cloudy",
      "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
      "code": 1003
    },
    "wind_mph": 3.8,
    "wind_kph": 6.1,
    "wind_degree": 200,
    "wind_dir": "SSW",
    "pressure_mb": 1014,
    "pressure_in": 29.93,
    "precip_mm": 0,
    "precip_in": 0,
    "humidity": 59,
    "cloud": 75,
    "feelslike_c": 24.8,
    "feelslike_f": 76.6,
    "windchill_c": 22.8,
    "windchill_f": 73,
    "heatindex_c": 24.8,
    "heatindex_f": 76.6,
    "dewpoint_c": 13.9,
    "dewpoint_f": 57,
    "vis_km": 16,
    "vis_miles": 9,
    "uv": 1,
    "gust_mph": 6.3,
    "gust_kph": 10.2
  }
}

Is my approach best practice? Or is there a better way to do this?
Any help would very appreicated!

You are doing it right. Optionally you can use cache function from react , although in next 14 force-cache is enabled by default. In next 15 rc cache is disabled by default. See more here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating

fetchCurrentData is returning the awaited Response from fetch, which is a container around your data. Return currentData.json() from fetchCurrentData  instead and currentWeather will look like the example JSON as an Object.

@LyndenNoye It seems this was what I was missing. Furthermore I was able to access localtime via currentWeather.location.localtime. Thank you for your help!

Using API Calls Directly in Components
If you prefer to make API calls directly within your components (e.g., in response to user actions), you can use fetch or axios:
// pages/index.js
   import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    function HomePage() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data');
      const currentWeather = await res.json();
      setData(currentWeather);
    }
    
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Data from API</h1>
      {/* Use data as per need */}
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;


The response object is usually a promise that should execute something when it's fulfilled (in this case the promise is fulfilled once the external api send the values).
To give an alternative to the async approach (I usually provide a function to execute):
fetch('https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?q=LOCATION&key=APIKEY').then(r=>r.json()).then((r)=>{console.log(r);setSomeState(r)});

Depending on your data/request scructure the r.json() parse doesn't make sense but in your case it should.
So since you are working with a function I would give the function a function parameter to be executed. Something like:
export function fetchCurrentData(onResult: (r) => void) {
    fetch('https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?q=LOCATION&key=APIKEY').then(r=>r.json()).then(onResult).catch(err => {
        // Handle errors
        console.error(err);
    });
}

In a component you could then call it with:
export default function DummyComponent() {
    const [state, setState] = useState();
    const collectData = useCallback(() => {
        fetchCurrentData((r) => setState(r));
    }, []);

    return <button onClick={collectData}>Collect Data</button>
}

